# Allusion in Nabokov's Pnin

Tags: russian-language, allusions, leo-tolstoy, vladimir-nabokov, pnin

In chapter 3, section 6 of Nabokov's *Pnin*, the main character is carrying a reference work "mainly devoted to Tolstoyana" across the Waindell campus when he drops it by accident:

> Pnin, on the dirty black ice of the flagged path, slipped again, threw up one arm in an abrupt convulsion, regained his balance, and, with a solitary smile, stooped to pick up *Zol. Fond Lit.*, which lay wide open to a [snapshot](https://www.circeinstitute.org/sites/default/files/styles/blog_full/public/field/image/blog_post/11.gif?itok=L6_pwAH4) of a Russian pasture with Lyov Tolstoy trudging across it toward the camera and some long-maned horses behind him, their innocent heads turned toward the photographer too.
>
> *V boyu li, v stranstvii, v volnah?* In fight, in travel, or in waves? Or on the Waindell campus?
>
> --Page 73 of the Vintage International edition

From which work is the passage in the second paragraph a quotation? (I tried Google, but I suspect the transliteration of the Russian is obscuring the search.) Why would Pnin think of this specific quotation after dropping the book and seeing this photo?

Answer (score 3):

It's from a poem of Pushkin's. An English translation is [here](http://www.pushkins-poems.com/). The relevant stanza:

> И где мне смерть пошлет судьбина?
> В бою ли, в странствии, в волнах?
> Или соседняя долина
> Мой примет охладелый прах?
>
> And where will fate send death to me?
> In battle, in my travels, or on the seas?
> Or will the neighbouring valley
> Receive my chilled ashes?

Possibly, the quote is brought to mind because Pnin nearly fell over, and he is worried he might have died. But somebody who has read *Pnin* more recently than I have might have a better explanation of why this quote came to mind.

Comment: I’m afraid “flight” was my typo for “fight”; I’ve corrected the question

Comment: I see now that this poem is the same one that Pnin teaches to his Elementary Russian students in an earlier chapter (2.3)